# Crude Rates word problems how to know of we have to multiply fraction eg. Deaths/total population by 1000, 10000, or 100000?

Tags: mean

I was solving crude rates word problems and wanted to ask why in some questions the fraction was multiplied by 1000 while in other questions it was multiplied by 10000 and 100000. How do we know which one do we have to multiply it with? (it isn't even mentioned in the question if we have to find per 1000 people or per 10000) Please help.

Comment: Use whatever you like: they are all equivalent, after all.

Answer (score 0):

It's just for convenience so that you don't have many decimal places before your number comes in.

The lower the expected fraction of cases, the higher the multiplier.

Perhaps stick with the conventional multiplier for a given application. If you write 1 per 1000 whereas the literature knew of 8 or 9 per 10 000, you might momentarily confuse the reader. If the 10 000 multiplier is a long standing convention, they might first read it as a huge decrease instead of the modest increase that it is.

The only thing you absolutely cannot do is report a multiplier that you didn't use.